# Making single tap look like double tap Android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm trying to hide my keyboard when Edittext is tapped.
problem is when setting an OnClickListener I have to double tap the Edittext if i want the hideKeyboard(); function to start.

Is it possible to set 2 OnClickListeners or something like that so it will appear like a double tap?

this is how i hide the keyboard:

```
    private void hideKeyboard() {
    System.out.println("Hiding keyboard");
    inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(this.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
}
```

Comment: You can just write  function to hide the keyboard on the onclick listener?

Comment: that's what i did but the first time you click the Edittext it gets focus the second the OnClickListener is activated. so i need a double tap while user only taps one time

Comment: don't add a onclick. write a method to show the keyboard on click

Comment: @Hades how do you do that?, and how will it help me?